# Toggle audio playback on keyboard key

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, keypress

Here is my code for 'click'- this works perfectly fine

```
masterPlay.addEventListener('click',() =>{
    if (audioElement.paused  || audioElement.currentTime<=0)
    {
        audioElement.play();
        masterPlay.classList.remove('fa-circle-play')
        masterPlay.classList.add('fa-circle-pause')
        gif.style.opacity = 1;
 
    }
    else 
    {
        audioElement.pause();
        masterPlay.classList.add('fa-circle-play')
        masterPlay.classList.remove('fa-circle-pause')
        gif.style.opacity = 0;

    }
})
```

here is my code for keypress which does not do anything.

```
document.getElementById("masterPlay").addEventListener('keypress',() =>{
    if (audioElement.paused  || audioElement.currentTime<=0)
    {
        audioElement.play();
        masterPlay.classList.remove('fa-circle-play')
        masterPlay.classList.add('fa-circle-pause')
        gif.style.opacity = 1;
 
    }
    else 
    {
        audioElement.pause();
        masterPlay.classList.add('fa-circle-play')
        masterPlay.classList.remove('fa-circle-pause')
        gif.style.opacity = 0;

    }
})
```

Please tell me the correct logic for the 'keypress' to work

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Why did you tag this question with jQuery? There is no jQuery in your code.

Comment: First one has `masterPlay` variable in the first line, the second doesn't.  Does your 2nd have `masterPlay` defined (*correctly*)? As you are attempting to use it.

Comment: The third question is... what keyboard key are you targeting?

Comment: Also, your `masterKey` needs to be focused (or a focusable element) in order to receive a key event - since it's the event delegator.

Comment: Anyways, you'll have to provide a [mcve]. Read [ask] and [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning a key listener to a specific element - which means it has to be focused in order to work. The best is to use a `<button>` element, and is needed use `.focus()` to focus it on DOM ready:

```js
const elPlay = document.querySelector("#play");
const elAudio = document.createElement("audio");
elAudio.src = "//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/39/Metallica_-_Enter_Sandman.ogg";

const masterToggle = () => {
  elAudio[elAudio.paused ? "play" : "pause"]();
  elPlay.classList.toggle("fa-circle-play",  elAudio.paused);
  elPlay.classList.toggle("fa-circle-pause", !elAudio.paused);
};

// Do on button click or on "Space" key (if button is focused):
elPlay.focus();
elPlay.addEventListener("click", masterToggle);
```

```css
#play.fa-circle-play::after{ content: "Play"; }
#play.fa-circle-pause::after{ content: "Pause"; }
```

```html
Click or press Space to toggle play:<br>
<button id="play" class="fa-circle-play" aria-label="Toggle audio play" type="button"></button>
```

If for some reason you need to assign a specific key, you could do in on the `window` level, using the `"keydown"` Event. In that case make also sure that the user is not typing into inputs, textareas, etc:

```js
const elPlay = document.querySelector("#play");
const elAudio = document.createElement("audio");
elAudio.src = "//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/39/Metallica_-_Enter_Sandman.ogg";

const masterToggle = () => {
  elAudio[elAudio.paused ? "play" : "pause"]();
  elPlay.classList.toggle("fa-circle-play",  elAudio.paused);
  elPlay.classList.toggle("fa-circle-pause", !elAudio.paused);
};

// Do on button click or on "Space" key (if button is focused):
elPlay.focus();
elPlay.addEventListener("click", masterToggle);

// Do on specific keyboard key ["P"]
addEventListener("keydown", (evt) => {
  // console.log(evt.code)
  if (
    evt.code === "KeyP" &&
    !evt.target.closest("input, textarea, [contenteditable]")
  ) {
    masterToggle();
  }
});
```

```css
#play.fa-circle-play::after{ content: "Play"; }
#play.fa-circle-pause::after{ content: "Pause"; }
```

```html
Click or press Space to toggle play:<br>
<button id="play" class="fa-circle-play" aria-label="Toggle audio play" type="button"></button>
```

Comment: Thankyou Buljan, it helped me for real .